How to use zparseopts to have both long and short options
I am trying to use zparseopts to get both long and short params, where one param is additive and the others are single set.
Example
foo.sh --pod longpod --pod longpod2 -p shortpod --from fromdate -t todate

which would have:
pods=(longpod longpod2 shortpod)
from='fromdate'
to='todate'

But, that's not what I get. Here is a sample script:
function main() {
  zparseopts -E -D -- \
           -pod+:=pods \
           -from::=from \
           -to::=to

  echo "pods: ${pods[@]}"
  echo "from: ${from}"
  echo "to ${to}"

}
main "${@}"

produces:
pods: --pod longpod --pod longpod2
from: --fromlongfrom
to --tolongto

It seems I misunderstand how to use this though because I am not getting what I expected.

This is a little closer, but it looks like zparseopts is always going to include the option names in the result array (e.g. --pod longpod). With optional arguments (::) it will always place the name and value in the same element (--fromlongfrom):
#!/usr/bin/env zsh
main() {
  zparseopts -E -D -- \
           -pod+:=pods \
           p+:=pods \
           -from::=from \
           t::=to
  typeset -p pods from to argv
}
main --pod longpod --pod longpod2 -p shortpod \
     --from fromdate -t todate --to longto
#=> typeset -g -a pods=( --pod longpod --pod longpod2 -p shortpod )
#=> typeset -g -a from=( --fromfromdate )
#=> typeset -g -a to=( -ttodate )
#=> typeset -g -a argv=( --to longto )

Post-processing can be used to remove the option names:
pods=(${pods:#(--pod|-p)})
from=${from#--from}
to=${to#-t}
typeset -p pods from to
#=> typeset -g -a pods=( longpod longpod2 shortpod )
#=> typeset -g from=fromdate
#=> typeset -g to=todate

TBH, I've quit trying to use zparseopts; among other things it doesn't support --opt=val style arguments, and there are some use cases that it does not handle well. A loop that steps through the arg list isn't much more complicated (also, this will accept --pod=name):
main() {
  local -a pods=(); local from= to=
  while ((#)); do
    case $1 in
      --pod=*)   argv[1]+=(${1#*=}) ;&
      -p|--pod)  shift; pods+=$1 ;;
      -f|--from) shift; from=$1 ;;
      -t|--to)   shift; to=$1 ;;
      --) break ;;
      -*) print -u2 "unknown option $1"; return 1 ;;
      *)  break ;;
    esac
    shift
  done
  if ! (($#pods)) { print -u2 "missing option -p / --pod"; return 1 }
  typeset -p pods from to argv
}


I was previously using getops and it wasn't behaving as it had when I used bash, so I thought I might be doing something wrong
